# .Net MemoryCache Miss when using Objects as Keys

Tags: c#, .net, caching, memorycache

When using `IMemoryCache` with an `object`, `TryGetValue` always miss. I am trying to have a `tuple<string, object>` as the key, and a `tuple<string, string>` works perfectly fine.

This code here always gets me a cache miss:

```
_cache.TryGetValue(("typeOfCache", query), out var something);
if(something == null) _cache.CreateEntry(("typeOfCache", query));
```

The object I'm using has lists of lists inside, not no dictionary/set (nothing that has a random ordering).

Is this a .net bug or am I doing something incorrectly?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

[`MemoryCache`](https://github.com/aspnet/caching/blob/master/src/Microsoft.Extensions.Caching.Memory/MemoryCache.cs) internally uses a `ConcurrentDictionary<object, CacheEntry>`, which in turn uses the default comparer for the `object` type, which performs equality comparisons based on the actual type's overrides of `Object.Equals` and `Object.GetHashCode`. In your case, your keys are `ValueTuple<string, Query>`, whatever your `Query` class is. [`ValueTuple<T1,T2>.Equals`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.valuetuple-2.equals) evaluates to true if the components of the compared instance are of the same types as those of the current instance, and if the components are equal to those of the current instance, with equality being determined by the default equality comparer for each component.

Thus, how the equality comparison gets performed depends on the implementation of your `Query` type. If this type does not override `Equals` and `GetHashCode`, nor implements `IEquatable<T>`, then reference equality is performed, meaning that you only get equality when you pass in the same instance of the query. If you want to alter this behavior, you should extend your `Query` class to implement `IEquatable<Query>`.

I also found that `CreateEntry` does not immediately add the new entry to the cache. .NET Core documentation is disappointingly sparse, so I haven't found the intended behavior; however, you can ensure that the entry is added by calling `Set` instead.

Example:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Caching.Memory;

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var query1 = new Query { Parts = { new List<string> { "abc", "def", "ghi" } } };
        var query2 = new Query { Parts = { new List<string> { "abc", "def", "ghi" } } };

        var memoryCache = new MemoryCache(new MemoryCacheOptions());
        memoryCache.Set(("typeOfCache", query1), new object());
        var found = memoryCache.TryGetValue(("typeOfCache", query2), out var something);
        Console.WriteLine(found);
    }

    public class Query : IEquatable<Query>
    {
        public List<List<string>> Parts { get; } = new List<List<string>>();

        public bool Equals(Query other)
        {
            if (ReferenceEquals(this, other)) return true;
            if (ReferenceEquals(other, null)) return false;
            return this.Parts.Length == other.Parts.Length 
                && this.Parts.Zip(other.Parts, (x, y) => x.SequenceEqual(y)).All(b => b);
        }

        public override bool Equals(object obj)
        {
            return Equals(obj as Query);
        }

        public override int GetHashCode()
        {
            return this.Parts.SelectMany(p => p).Take(10).Aggregate(17, (acc, p) => acc * 23 + p?.GetHashCode() ?? 0);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Ahhh, it makes sense now. I’ll make sure the objects override Equals or simply serialize them. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Welcome. Don't forget to override `GetHashCode` too; dictionaries use it for lookups. Two objects that are equal must return the same hash.

Comment: @Douglas - Any chance you could demystify what you're doing in GetHashCode with all of that LINQ, and how it ensures two instances of Query will generate the same hash code if their Parts have value equality?

Comment: @bubbleking: The `GetHashCode` method combines the hash codes of the first ten elements from the flattened `Parts` list. The `Aggregate` operator uses the popular pattern for combining multiple hash codes using primes; see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/263416/1149773).

Comment: So then, why 10?  Won't that lead to the same hashcode being generated for two collections with 11+ elements even if the 11th (or higher) elements in them are not the same?

Comment: @bubbleking: Correct. Hash codes aren't expected to be unique, just well distributed. Importantly, hash codes need to be computed fast, which leads to this trade-off of considering just 10 elements. If distribution is more important than performance in your scenario, you can remove that `Take(10)`.